# Django models for school timetable?

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design, django-orm

I am building a school timetable app for each room? There are my models. Is there anything i am missing?

```
class Building(models.Model):
      bid = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['bid']

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.bid}'


class Room(models.Model):
      building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      related_name='rooms')
      number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
      availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      power = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['building', 'number']
    unique_together = ['building', 'number']

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.building.bid}/{self.number}'

class Occurrence(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    start_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='start_at')
    end_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='end_at')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Period(models.Model):
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
    objects = PeriodManager()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['start']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.start}-{self.end}'

    def check_time(self):
        return True if self.start < self.end else False

    def check_overlap(self):
        pass


   class TimetableModel(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            abstract =True
```

There will be a model name Booking which extends from Occurrence to allow students register to use a room in periods. I would like to make a Timetable model link to a Room Model for providing to context for rendering different weeks timetable for a room  and Period models which are resemble school periods. Any advises?

Comment: What's the problem or issue you're facing? Just asking us to review your models and give advice isn't the purpose of SO, and makes your question too vague. Please check the guidelines on [Ask].

Comment: I would like to make a Timetable model link to a Room Model for providing to context for rendering different weeks timetable for a room .

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to re-think your actual models and what you're trying to achieve.

Having a look at your models you seemed to create models for different aspects of what you're trying to do but there doesn't seems to be coherence between the models.

For instance one way to look at it would be as follows:

```
Building
- Name

Room
- Number 
- Building (FK)

Booking
- Room
- Period (you could just have statically defined list assume these are fixed)
- Duration (number of periods, this removes the need to specify end as you can calculate it.
```

To make a booking you need to know the following:
- The room you want to book
- The period you want to use it 
- How long you'd like to book it for (ie. 2 periods)

From a data perspective that's probably the simplest models you can build (simple is always better). In terms of showing what is available you can do that at the point where you're making a booking (booking form).

I hope that gives you some idea of how to approach this, I didn't create models in this answer as I think your question wasn't really a technical how to but more of a point in the right direction.